# Why 'Any' can be down casted to any function?

Tags: ios, swift

I have encountered strange behavior of the type 'Any' of Swift.
My code

```
print( ( {} as Any ) as? Int->() )
```

shows message below on console.

> Optional((Function))

But I think 'as?' must fail and the message should be

> Optional(nil)

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, in Xcode 7.3, it shows 'nil'.